# Compiling Python to a static lib

Tags: python, c++, static, .lib

How I can compile python2.7 to a static lib in Windows? And how I can use these lib within my project (with Python embedded Python C/API).

Comment: What is the question? What "python" do you want to compile? A python script? And what is "Python embedded Python C/API" supposed to mean?

Comment: I guess Dmitry is trying to compile python2.7.dll as static lib, to use Python C API in his C++ program without installing Python on system.

Comment: @Arkady That's right.

Comment: I will follow this topic, if someone will tell you solution. I failed with trying to use Python C API without Python installation.

Comment: By looking at the `makefile` and `configure.sh`, the `makefile` defines a `$LIBRARY` target and the `configure.sh` script defines that as [this](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/474c97a5f0c8/configure#l5410). Similar targets must exist for MSVC.

Comment: For the `nmake` build, I think [this](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/474c97a5f0c8/PC/python3.mak#l4) might be the target you want.

Comment: I create static lib. But next question is how I can include it(.lib) in main program on C++?

Comment: That will just require using the desired functions in the C++ program, calling the necessary initialisation functions, and linking to the Python library with the appropriate linker flags. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @dilbert I use VS 2010 for compiling